# NJ 1040 Dividends

Tags: united-states, taxes, state-income-tax, new-jersey, qualified-dividend

For the NJ 1040 do you add together your ordinary dividends and qualified dividends or are the qualified dividends already part of the ordinary dividends and I should just report the ordinary dividend number?

I don't want to make the mistake of adding them together and paying more tax then I should.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

*Some* ordinary dividends are qualified dividends for Federal tax purposes and some or not.  If NJ doesn't treat qualified dividends differently, then just report the ordinary dividends and ignore the fact that some of them are qualified dividends for Federal income tax purposes.

Comment: Note however **short-term gain distributions** (from mutual funds) are included in 1099-DIV 1a (not 2a) and go on Fed schedule B and new-1040 line 3b, but for NJ they should be excluded from NJ1040 line 17 and instead added to schedule DOP (which otherwise is mostly equal to Fed D) on line 2 and NJ1040 line 19.